# can't clone a map in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have read the wikis and know the recipe for cloning maps (one piece of paper next to a map) but when I put them in their associated slots, there is nothing in the 'created' box for me to get. There is supposed to be 2xmaps in that slot so that when I click on it, I get my map and a duplicate.

Am I doing something wrong or is there some special trick I don't know about?

For what it's worth, I am playing single player survival.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have the recipe wrong. The correct recipe is a Map and an Empty Map, not a Map and a piece of paper.

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map#Cloning